# How to use properly Azure app configuration with key vault reference in a function app?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-keyvault, azure-app-configuration

I have a problem with the Azure app configuration - key vault reference. Currently, I have an app configuration key (FunctionApp:Replication:Regions) with many values (asia, we, sae).So the connection is one to many. I added key-vault reference to each value. But the problem is that I don't know how to read the data from the function app, to get the value in the key vault.

Currently, I am using two services:

`ConfigurationClient` - To get the all values in one key.

`IConfigurationRefresher` to refresh the app configuration, to get the latest changes that are made, without the need of a function restart.

Example (StorageService):

```
private readonly ConfigurationClient _client;
private readonly IConfigurationRefresher _configurationRefresher;

public StorageService(ConfigurationClient client, IConfigurationRefresherProvider refresherProvider)
        {
            _client = client,
            _configurationRefresher = refresherProvider.Refreshers.First();
        }

SettingSelector settingSelector = new SettingSelector()
            {
                KeyFilter = "FunctionApp:Replication:Regions"
            };

var regions = _client.GetConfigurationSettings(settingSelector).ToList();
```

Example (Startup):

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder){
    ConfigurationClient appConfigurations = new 
    ConfigurationClient(appConfigurationsConnectionString);

    builder.Services.AddSingleton<ConfigurationClient>(appConfigurations);

}

public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
       {
           builder.ConfigurationBuilder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
           {
               options.Connect(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionString")).Select("FunctionApp:*").ConfigureRefresh(refreshOptions =>
               {
                   refreshOptions.Register("FunctionApp:Replication:Regions", refreshAll: true);
               });
           });
       }
```

When i try to get the values -  `var regions = _client.GetConfigurationSettings(settingSelector).ToList();`
, it returns this :

```
{"uri":"https://appconfigurationkeyvalut.vault.azure.net/secrets/tableasia"},

{"uri":"https://appconfigurationkeyvalut.vault.azure.net/secrets/tablewe"},

{"uri":"https://appconfigurationkeyvalut.vault.azure.net/secrets/tablesea"}
```

And i dont know how to get the value from the key vault. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In Azure App Configuration, follow [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/use-key-vault-references-dotnet-core#add-a-key-vault-reference-to-app-configuration) and create key vault references for the following keys:

   - FunctionApp:Replication:Regions:Asia
   - FunctionApp:Replication:Regions:We
   - FunctionApp:Replication:Regions:Sea
2. Follow [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-azure-functions-csharp) and create an Azure Function. Note that you shouldn't use `ConfigurationClient`. It will not resolve the key vault reference for you. The `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration` library will resolve the key vault reference and make secret values available in `IConfiguration`.
3. Enable dynamic configuration for your function app by following [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/enable-dynamic-configuration-azure-functions-csharp?tabs=in-process). You should use a sentinel key for configuration change monitoring. The `startup.cs` looks something like this:

```
public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
{
    builder.ConfigurationBuilder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
    {
        options.Connect(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionString"))
                // Load all keys that start with `FunctionApp:` and have no label
                .Select("FunctionApp:*")
                // Configure to reload configuration if the registered sentinel key is modified
                .ConfigureRefresh(refreshOptions =>
                    refreshOptions.Register("FunctionApp:Sentinel", refreshAll: true));
    });
}
```

4. The secret value of your key vault references are accessible via `IConfiguration` automatically in your `Run` function. For example, `_configuration["FunctionApp:Replication:Regions:Asia"]`.